# function to insert image into org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Is there a function I can call that will automatically insert an image into an org-mode buffer in this format

```
#+CAPTION: Foo of the caption 
#+NAME:   fig:SED-HR4049
[[/Users/peter/images/2013-11-22.jpg]]
```

by prompting me for the caption and the URL/path for the image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

org-mode itself does not seem to have a built-in function for doing this.

If you want to avoid writing custom Elisp, you can either use yasnippet and customize the org-mode ["figure" snippet](https://github.com/AndreaCrotti/yasnippet-snippets/blob/master/org-mode/figure) to something like

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: figure
# key: fig
# --
#+CAPTION: ${1:caption}
#+LABEL: fig:${2:label}
[[${3:link}]]
```

or add a couple of custom ["Easy Templates"](http://orgmode.org/manual/Easy-Templates.html) to `org-structure-template-alist`, e.g.

```lisp
(setq org-structure-template-alist
      (quote ((...)               ; Default templates ...
              (...)               ; ...
              ("C" "#+CAPTION ?") ; Template for caption.
              ("P" "[[?]]")       ; Template for image link.
                                  ; Could also replace "?" with "%file"
                                  ; which prompts for a file name
                                  ; BUT inserts double quotes around it
                                  ; that you would have to remove afterwards
              )))
```